# CakePHP beforeFind() stops saving

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have a model for some products in CakePHP and as a default I need to return just products whith quantity > 0 for every find(). So I implemented this in beforeFind:

```
public function beforeFind($query) {
    // As default, search only media with a quantity > 0
    if (!isset($query['conditions']['Medium.quantity'])) {
        $query['conditions']['Medium.quantity >'] = 0;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Every time I need to show also products with quantity = 0, I set 'callbacks' => false for find().
Problem: When I try to update a product with quantity of 0 to some higher quantity, it doesn't work. Somehow beforeFind() is called before saving, when I comment it out, it works fine.

Code for editing a product:

```
if ($this->request->is(['post','put'])) {
            $this->Medium->id = $id;
            if ($this->Medium->save($this->request->data, array('callbacks' => false))) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The medium has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $id]);
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update the medium.'));
        }
```

As you can see, I tried setting callbacks to false for saving too and it doesn't work.

Has anyone an idea how to disable beforeFind when saving/updating?

Thanks!

PS: I'm using CakePHP 2.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually with you using `$this->Medium->id = $id`, which does an internal find on $id. Instead, try using `$this->request->data['Medium']['id'] = $id`. Model::save doesn't invoke find callbacks, only save callbacks (beforeSave, afterSave).

Edit: The issue could also be validation errors, which you don't seem to be checking for, if you have validation rules set on the model.